# Refinerycms undefined method 'title_with_meta'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I'm migrating my refinerycms project to production and i'm now getting the error

```
 NoMethodError in Refinery/admin/pages#index

Showing /var/www/vhosts/tomstestsite.us/PersonalTrainingKT/app/views/refinery/admin/pages/_page.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `title_with_meta' for #<Refinery::Page:0x000000083d5538>

Extracted source (around line #10):

7:     <% end %>
8: 
9:     <span class='title <%= 'toggle' if page.children.present? %>'>
10:       <%= page.title_with_meta.html_safe %>
11:       <% if Refinery.i18n_enabled? and Refinery::I18n.frontend_locales.many? %>
12:         <span class='preview'>
13:           <% page.translations.each do |translation| %>
```

What would cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that Refinery::Page does not have a title_with_meta method defined on it. Not sure what version you're using, but as of [this commit](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/commit/7dca4374087b067f7b6fa562c8123db8a0e5526e), title_with_meta was moved to the [page helper](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/pages/app/helpers/refinery/admin/pages_helper.rb#L28-49).

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.6. How can i tell what version that commit was made in and how can i fix the issue?

Comment: The change was made in 2.0.6, see the [changelog](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/changelog.md#206-6-august-2012). As far as how to fix it I have no idea, I've never used Refinery CMS.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've tried updating to version 2.0.6 for my go-live because i was pointing at a github development branch for another fix.

Comment: Since i had overridden all of the view files, my view files didn't get updated when i upgraded my version of refinerycms. I had to manually copy the view files from the changlog that you posted. Thanks for posting that.